# Dynamique combobox return 'undefined ' instead of displaying the 'nom' of 'technicien'

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-5

I have the form below, with 4 comboboxes "Metier=profession" "tache=task" "tacrification=pricing" and "technicien=technician", and the name of technican is on table user                                                                 Dynamique combobox return 'undefined ' name variable when i choose technicien but when i make id on script it work

[image]

interventioncontroller

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use App\zoneintervention;
 use App\technicien;
 use App\Intervention;
 use App\metier;
 use App\tache;
 use App\client;
 use App\user;
 use App\adresse;
 use App\Tarification;
 use App\tarificationtache;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use App\Http\Requests\InterventionRequest;
 use DB;
 class InterventionController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
 $Listintervention=Intervention::with(['technicien','client', 
 'tarificationtache'])->get();

    return view('intervention.index',['interventions'=>$Listintervention]);


}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()

{
    $user=  user::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
    $client = client::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
    $metiers = metier::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
    $technicien = Technicien::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    $tarifications = tarificationtache::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

    return view('intervention.create')->with('technicien', $technicien)- 
 >with('client',$client)->with('metiers',$metiers)- 
 >with('tarifications',$tarifications);
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(InterventionRequest $request)
{
    $intervention = new Intervention();

    $intervention ->description =$request->input('description');
    $intervention ->duree_prevu =$request->input('duree_prevu');


    if($request->has('statut')){
    $intervention->statut = $request->input('statut');
    }else{
           $intervention->statut = 0;
    }

    $intervention ->technicien_id = $request->input('technicien_id');
    $intervention ->client_id = $request->input('client_id');
    $intervention ->tarification_id = $request->tarificationtache_id;
    $intervention->save();
    return redirect('intervention');




}

public function prodfunct(){

    $technicien=technicien::all();//get data from table
    return redirect('intervention',compact('technicien'));//sent data to 
 view

}
public function findlibelle_metier(Request $request){


    $metier=metier::all();//get data from table
    return redirect('intervention',compact('metier'));//sent data to view
}

public function findProductName(Request $request){
    //if our chosen id and products table prod_cat_id col match the get 
first 100 data
    //$request->id here is the id of our chosen option id
    $data=tache::select('libelle_tache','id')->where('metier_id',$request- 
>id)->take(100)->get();
    return response()->json($data);//then sent this data to ajax success
}


/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show( $id)
{
    $intervention=Intervention::find($id);
    $technicien = $intervention->technicien;
    $tarificationtache = tarificationtache::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    return view('intervention.show',['intervention'=>$intervention])- 
>with('technicien',$technicien)->with('tarificationtache',   
$tarificationtache);
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{

    $intervention=Intervention::find($id);
    return view('intervention.edit',['intervention'=>$intervention]);

}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(InterventionRequest $request, $id)
{
    $intervention=Intervention::find($id);
    $intervention ->date_intervention =$request->input('date_intervention');
    $intervention ->description =$request->input('description');
    $intervention ->duree_prevu =$request->input('duree_prevu');
    $intervention ->statut =$request->has('statut');

    $intervention->save();
    return redirect('intervention');

}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    $intervention =intervention::find($id);
    $intervention->delete();
    return redirect('intervention');
}

}
```

create.blade.php

```
    @extends('Layouts/app')
@extends('Layouts/master')
@section('content')
<!--  jQuery -->
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var getTachesByMetierUrl = "{{url('/tachesbymetier')}}";
    var getAdresseByClientUrl = "{{url('/adressebyclient')}}";
    var getTarificationsByTacheUrl = "{{url('/tarificationsbytache')}}";
    var getTechniciensByTarificationtacheUrl = " 
 {{url('/techniciensbytarificationtache')}}";



    function getAdresseByClient(val) {
        if(val.length>0) {
            var client_id = val;
            $.get(getAdresseByClientUrl+'/'+client_id,function(res) {
                var html = '<option value="">-Select-</option>' ;
                $.each(res.adresses,function(index,item) {
                    html+='<option 
  value="'+item.id+'">'+item.code_postal+'</option>';
                });
                $('#adresses').html(html);

            });
        }
    }


    function getTachesByMetier(val) {
        if(val.length>0) {
            var metier_id = val;
            $.get(getTachesByMetierUrl+'/'+metier_id,function(res) {
                var html = '<option value="">-Select-</option>' ;
                $.each(res.taches,function(index,item) {
                    html+='<option 
  value="'+item.id+'">'+item.libelle_tache+'</option>';
                });
                $('#taches').html(html);

            });
        }
    }

     function getTechniciensByTache(val) {
        if(val.length>0) {
            var tache_id = val;

 $.get(getTechniciensByTacheUrl+'/'+tarificationtache_id,function(res) {
                var html = '<option value="">-Select-</option>' ;
                $.each(res.techniciens,function(index,item) {
                    html+='<option 
 value="'+item.id+'">'+item.id.nom+'</option>';
                });
                $('#techniciens').html(html);

            });
        }
    }
  function getTarificationsByTache(val) {

        if(val.length>0) {
            var tache_id = val;
            $.get(getTarificationsByTacheUrl+'/'+tache_id,function(res) {
                var html = '<option value="">-Select-</option>' ;
                $.each(res.tarifications,function(index,item) {
                    html+='<option 
 value="'+item.id+'">'+item.tarif+'</option>';
                });
                $('#tarifications').html(html);

            });
        }
    }

    function getTechniciensByTarificationtache(val) {
        if(val.length>0) {
            var tarificationtache_id = val;
  $.get(getTechniciensByTarificationtacheUrl+'/'+tarificationtache_id, 
  function(res ) {
                var html = '<option value="">-Select-</option>' ;
                $.each(res.techniciens,function(index,item) {
                    html+='<option 
 value="'+item.id+'">'+item.id.nom+'</option>';
                });
                $('#techniciens').html(html);

            });
        }
    }
</script>
@if(count($errors))
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors ->all() as $message)
                <li>{{$message}}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <h1>Ajout Intervention</h1>
        <form action=" {{url ('intervention')  }}" method="post">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="client">Client</label>
                <select onchange="getAdresseByClient(this.value)" 
 name="client_id" id="client" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">-Select-</option>
                    @foreach($client as $t)
                        <option value="{{$t->id }}">
                            {{$t->user->nom}}
                        </option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">date et heure </label>
                <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local"  name 
  ="duree_prevu" value="{{old('duree_prevu')}}">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">description</label>
                <input type="text"  name ="description" class="form- 
 control"value="{{old('description')}}">
            </div>

    <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>Metier: </label>
                <select onchange="getTachesByMetier(this.value)" 
 style="width: 200px" class="productm form-control" id="metiers">
               <option value="">-Select-</option>
                    @foreach($metiers as $t)
                        <option value="{{$t->id }}">
                            {{$t->libelle_metier}}
                        </option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>tache: </label>
                <select onchange="getTarificationsByTache(this.value)" 
 style="width: 200px" class="productname form-control" name="tache" 
 id="taches">
                <option value="">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>tarification: </label>
                <select 
onchange="getTechniciensByTarificationtache(this.value)" style="width: 
200px" 
class="productname form-control" name="tarificationtache_id" 
id="tarifications">
                <option value="">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label>technicien: </label>
                        <select style="width: 200px" class="productname 
 form-control" name="technicien_id" id="technicien">
                            <option value="">-Select-</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>



</div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">statut    :   </label>
                <input type="checkbox"  name ="statut" value="1" required 
 autofocus>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">payement</label>
                <input type="checkbox"  name ="payement" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">

                <input type="submit" value = "enregistrer" class="form- 
control btn btn-primary">
            </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<link 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
 rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap- 
datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"> 
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap- 
datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

@endsection
```

table technicien

```
Schema::create('techniciens', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->boolean('actif')->default(1);
        $table->float('moyenne_avis')->nullable();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->datetime('deleted_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

    });
```

*

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
html+='<option value="'+item.id+'">'+item.id.nom+'</option>';
```

you need:

```
html+='<option value="'+item.id+'">'+item.user.nom+'</option>';
```

And change this:

```
public function getTechniciensByTarificationtache($tarificationtache_id) 
   { 
      $t = tarificationtache::with('techniciens.user')->find($tarificationtache_id); 
          return response()->json(['techniciens' => $t->techniciens]); 
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help 
I work with "getTechniciensByTarificationtache"   
same problem when I tried your rethinking the

Comment: @chagou2704 you changed code in two places and it still not works?

Comment: @ yrv16 yes it not works        
for more explanation I have 2 table tarificationtache  and technicien whith mony to mony relation ship and technicien inherits the 'nom' from  the table user

Comment: @chagou2704 Which controller method is called for ajax request in getTechniciensByTarificationtache?

Comment: @ yrv16 yes  getTechniciensByTarificationtache   and i called this function on techniciencontrooler whith this code                          public function getTechniciensByTarificationtache($tarificationtache_id)
    {
        $t = tarificationtache::find($tarificationtache_id);
        return response()->json(['techniciens' => $t->techniciens]);
    }

Comment: @chagou2704 I am asking which method handle this URL getTechniciensByTarificationtacheUrl. Show me controller method for this URL.

Comment: @chagou2704 Can you show techniciens table structure?

Comment: @ yrv16 i have added the technciens table on my question

Comment: @chagou2704 Do you have a relation in techncien model for getting user data? Because you need `nom` and it is in user table. So you need this relation to get this `nom` property.

Comment: @ yrv16 of caurs i have this                                                          
    public function  user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

Comment: @ yrv16 NOW NOTHING IS DISPLAYED IN THE TECHNICIEN FIELD

Comment: @chagou2704 Can you `console.log(res.techniciens)` and show me result?

Comment: @ yrv16 i do not know how to do can you explain please

Comment: @chagou2704 Add `console.log(res.techniciens)` aftre `var html = '<option value="">-Select-</option>' ;` and open devTools (F12) then go to console tab and there you will see your object structure.

Comment: @ yrv16 when i choise a tarification i have this erreur

Comment: GET http://localhost/projet/public/techniciensbytarificationtache/4 500 (Internal Server Error) send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
r.(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:4
getTechniciensByTarificationtache @ create:204
onchange @ create:298
ListPicker._handleMouseUp

Comment: @chagou2704 `localhost/projet/public/techniciensbytarificationtache/4 ` put this in browser URL and make screenshot for result page then attach it here in order to see error.

Comment: @chagou2704 I updeted answer

Comment: @ yrv16 thak you so much i have another quastion if you have time can you help me

Comment: @chagou2704 Create new topic for new question.

Comment: @ yrv16  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50466418/how-to-display-a-table-from-dynamic-combobox